# android: Уменьшение картинки при нажатии двумя пальцами

Tags: java, android

Как можно уменьшить (zoom out) картинку с помощью нажатия [двумя пальцами](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/gestures.html#gestures-touch-mechanics) (Two-fingers touch) ?

Вот мой кусок кода: Что нужно добавить в `if` чтобы `mImageView` стала стандартным размером?

```
ImageView mImageView;
mImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        int action = motionEvent.getAction();
        int fingersCount = motionEvent.getPointerCount();
        if((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) && (fingersCount == 2)){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Double tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определил жест -> изменил картинку. Много способов, вот один из.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/touchevent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView myTouchEvent;
    ImageView myImageView;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    int bmpWidth, bmpHeight;

    int touchState;
    final int IDLE = 0;
    final int TOUCH = 1;
    final int PINCH = 2;
    float dist0, distCurrent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myTouchEvent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.touchevent);
        myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_logo);
        bmpWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        bmpHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        distCurrent = 1;
        dist0 = 1;
        drawMatrix();
        myImageView.setOnTouchListener(MyOnTouchListener);
        touchState = IDLE;

    }

    private void drawMatrix(){
        float curScale = distCurrent/dist0;
        if (curScale < 0.1){
            curScale = 0.1f;
        }

        Bitmap resizedBitmap;
        int newHeight = (int) (bmpHeight * curScale);
        int newWidth = (int) (bmpWidth * curScale);
        resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
    }

    View.OnTouchListener MyOnTouchListener
            = new View.OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            float distx, disty;

            switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    myTouchEvent.setText("ACTION_DOWN");
                    touchState = TOUCH;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    myTouchEvent.setText("ACTION_POINTER_DOWN");
                    touchState = PINCH;

                    distx = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
                    disty = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
                    dist0 = (float) Math.sqrt(distx * distx + disty * disty);

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    myTouchEvent.setText("ACTION_MOVE");

                    if(touchState == PINCH){
                        distx = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
                        disty = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
                        distCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt(distx * distx + disty * disty);
                        drawMatrix();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    myTouchEvent.setText("ACTION_UP");
                    touchState = IDLE;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    myTouchEvent.setText("ACTION_POINTER_UP");
                    touchState = TOUCH;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: я добавил свой код, помоги дополнить.

Comment: Так такой же слушатель).
Мой код полностью рабочий, картинку ток вставь в imageView свою и будет работать. Там правда две TextView, для примера показаны удалишь если будут мешаться.